# Cannot understand the reason of why HDFS can scale to a large number of concurrent clients

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Recently I read the book 《Hadoop:The definitive Guide》, I met one paragraph which I cannot understand,

"One important aspect of this design is that the client contacts datanodes directly to
retrieve data and is guided by the namenode to the best datanode for each block. This
design allows HDFS to scale to a large number of concurrent clients because the data
traffic is spread across all the datanodes in the cluster."

I cannot understand why the author says "This design allows HDFS to scale to a large number of concurrent clients", although he explained the reason that "because the data
traffic is spread across all the datanodes in the cluster " but I cannot understand his words, can someone explain it to me in a easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single namenode which knows on which datanodes the blocks for a given file are located.

Imagine your HDFS has a file of size 1024 MB, split into 8 blocks of size 128 MB. Let's imagine those blocks are conveniently distributed on 8 different nodes.

When your client needs to download the file it will ask the namenode for it. If the namenode wanted to return the file itself, it would have to download it from all the datanodes first, and then return them one by one to the client. This is grossly inefficient because the namenode would have to serve all clients on its own, and waste memory/cpu to store and serve intermediate data. If 2 clients requested the same file at the same time, the namenode would have to serve 16 blocks in total to the clients.

What would be efficient, though, is if your client directly downloaded 1 block from each machine. That way if you had 2 clients requesting the same file, each datanode would only have to serve 2 blocks simultaneoulsy.

When you use a HDFS client, for example the FS shell which comes with your hadoop installation and is callable via `hdfs dfs -<cmd>` or `hadoop fs -<cmd>`, the client asks the namenode for the file, on port 9000 by default. The namenode returns the URIs of the different blocks on the different datanodes. The client can download the blocks from separate datanodes, usually on port 50010, the data transfer port.

If you use the FS shell to download a file, and monitor the network on your client machine, you will see that it downloads blocks directly from different datanodes. Here is an example downloading a 4-block file and monitoring the network with the `tcptrack` tool.

[image]

This relieves the namenode, spreading out the workload, and also enables the client to make simultaneous downloads of blocks from multiple datanodes. You can see that in the screenshot, where 2 connections are active and 1 connection is closing from 3 different IP addresses (datanodes).

When all downloads are finished to client concatenates all blocks to obtain the full file.